# Why is AIDL/Messenger bound to a Service?

Tags: java, android, ipc, aidl

Scenario: I have a `Controller` (normal Java class) that must be able to pilot several `Slave`s.

A `Slave`'s nature can differ, so that it can either be:

1. A `Service`, let's call it a `ServiceSlave`: the lifecycle of this object usually differs from the application's components (say, it does not depend on the current activity)
2. A simple Java class, say a `ObjectSlave`: the lifecycle of this object is somewhat bound to the scope in which it is created (say, the current activity)

What these two types of `Slave`s have in common, is that **they can reside in different processes**.

---

Because of this last "requirement", I immediately turned my attention to `AIDL`/`Messenger` as the form of communication between a `Controller` and a `Slave`, since it provides IPC.

However, it seems that `AIDL` (and in turn `Messenger`, since it should be based on AIDL as well) **has only been defined if you are to work with a `Service`**. That is, there is no way for me to implement an `AIDL`-based interface without an `IBinder` object, which usually is provided in the `onServiceConnected` method.

**FIRST QUESTION**: can `AIDL` really be used only when dealing with a `Service`? If it is, why so?

Now, consider my scenario. I would like, as any other good developer would, to write a single, elegant interface that allows the `Controller` to pilot every `Slave`, regardless of their nature. The only solution that came to my mind so far involves using `Intent`s and `BroadcastReceiver`s, all conveniently wrapped in dedicated Java classes.

**SECOND QUESTION**: is this the only viable way? Am I overseeing something?

---

**EDIT**

I guess I should've given more details on what the `Controller` element actually does. It is a component that is loosely coupled with several UI widgets, who subscribe to it. It has been designed (willingly) so that it doesn't need a reference to a `Context`. So it doesn't *need* or *use* UI widgets directly, but in turn those widgets depend on the `Controller`.

Comment: OK, with your edited info, I'm confused about what the real goal of the Controller/Slave paradigm is.  If it is completely internal to an `Activity` in your app (without requiring the `Context`) then you don't want a `Service`, AIDL or `Messenger` at all.  Those are all used when you cross process boundaries or (`Service`) have something running which is not UI centric.  If you're just using this as an internal publish-subscribe type system then you'll have to define the classes and interfaces.  That being said, you may want to look at EventBus or Otto as possible 3rd party helpers.

Comment: OK, so I clearly have problems in explaining this :) My main question is regarding how to communicate between the `Controller` and the `Slave`, where the latter may or may not be a `Service`. The communication must be inter-process (since `Controller` and `Slave` may be running on different processes), but it may also be inside the same process.

Comment: But, is the `Controller` only present when the owning `Activity` is running?

Comment: No, there are circumstances where the `Controller` is not tied to an `Activity`, but instead lives inside a `Service`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good, but not a simple question to answer.  Like most things, there are multiple approaches to take to solve this type of problem.  The first thing to examine is whether or not your `Controller` needs or uses a UI component.  If not, then you'll need to encapsulate it in a `Service`.  `Activity` lifecycle is such that it will only be running when it is the current thing on screen.  As soon as the user presses HOME or BACK it is either stopped or destroyed, respectively.  Starting another app via notification or from within your app will have an effect similar to pressing HOME: your `Activity` will be paused.

So, assuming you don't need/want UI for your `Controller`, you have numerous things at your disposal:

1. Make your service a "bound" service by exposing a custom AIDL interface.  Not difficult, but not for the feint of heart either.
2. Make your service respond to custom `Intent`s to take some action.  The `Service` could then fire back broadcasts or start a specific "slave" `Activity`.  If interested in this, explore the use of the `IntentService` to better manage the threading and prevent ANR of your app.
3. Similar to the previous, use a custom `Intent` and have your slave send a `Messenger` object it has created as an extra within the `Intent`.  At that point the `Service` can send messages to the `Messenger`, which is owned by the slave `Activity` and will be delivered to a specific `Handler`.

You do not need a custom AIDL exposed interface for options 2 and 3.  You are correct in that you must define an AIDL interface if you are going to use a bound service and your `Service.onBind()` method must return an instance of your binder interface stub implementation.

All of that being said, you could use any of the 3 approaches to meet your goal of working with slave classes which reside in either `Activity` or `Service` instances.  The advantage of using the AIDL or `Messenger` approaches is a reduction in context switching (more efficient) since you're not sending `Intent` objects.  Each time you send an `Intent`, the sender contacts the `ActivityManagerService` running in a system process to resolve where the `Intent` is to be delivered.  With AIDL and `Messenger`, only the initial `bindService()` or `startService()` calls reach out to the `ActivityManagerService`.  After that point the communication is performed using direct binders between the two processes.

Comment: Nice aggregation ! Can you point out the open source native applications using these concepts ?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out `AIDL` and `Binder` are not tied to `Service`s.

While it is true that a `IBinder` reference is provided only when binding to a `Service`, the framework offers the [`Binder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html) class, which already implements the [`IBinder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html) interface.

Moreover, a `Binder` instance works transparently across processes and it is not required to live in a `Service` context.

---

[still elaborating, will provide a scheme on how the structure can be implemented by directly using a Binder instance]